# Two questions about Taoism

Tags: taoism

I am reading the "Tao Te Ching", and I was asking myself two questions :

-Why Lao-Tzeu's style in "Tao Te Ching" is so difficult to interpret ?

-Is the Way (the Tao) like an inner will, a will incorrupted by no external consciousness and which guides the self in the World?

Comment: Cabalistic???...

Comment: Might be a variant of "Kabbalah"/"Qabalah." If so, it would historically be more that de Leon's text hearkened back to Laozi's text, I suppose. Granted, de Leon claimed that the *Zohar* was carried over from an oral tradition going back to Moses, and IIRC there were Catholic officers called "figurists" or something who believed that Enoch might've been Laozi, no less.

Comment: As for describing the Tao as an inner will, to confine it to such a description seems to fly in the face of the whole "the Tao that can be named is not the real Tao." But *wu wei* might comport with one's sense of a Tao-infused will, so there might not be too much distance between the notions.

Comment: *Wu wei*, popularly translated as "doing nothing" is more accurately "being nothing" as in not-thinking (cutting mentation), not clinging to views (being like water), but still getting on with the necessary.  This is the way.

Comment: @KristianBerry Your (first) comment makes for a potentially very interesting answer

Comment: I was mistaken about the Laozi = Enoch claim, it seems the figurists said [Fuxi = Enoch](https://www.mdpi.com/2077-1444/14/2/263/pdf) instead. [This dissertation](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/76394697.pdf) explores figurist reflections on the *Book of Changes*. I wish I could find a thorough online copy of the *Zohar*, but I tried to do so while going over a passage from Martin Buber of late, and wasn't able to line up Buber with the *Zohar* sections that were available.

Comment: See [Daoism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/daoism/).

Comment: It's just Nonduality, It is not complicated.

Comment: @ScotteRowe la non dualité ?

Comment: @Olandelie: see [nondualism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondualism). The general idea is that the universe is singular whole with no divisions, and that the divisions we *see* are merely perceptual: concepts we impose on the world through the limitations of thought and sensory abilities. A lot of Eastern (and some Western) mysticisms advocate efforts to *see* the world as an undivided whole, to overcome the illusion of divisions.

Comment: All that I brought to the party is: The Tao that can be named is *not* the Real Tao.

Answer (score 5):

Just a note: the pinyin romanization of Chinese characters is the international standard, but the Wade-Giles system is still used in the West for a lot of early-translated major texts. I'll be using dao, daodejing, Laozi, and other pinyin forms instead of the older (W_G) Tao, Tao Te Ching, Lao Tzu, yadda yadda. Different English spellings of the same words; don't let it be confusing.

The essence of the daodejing is that we humans understand the world primarily in language, but that the world we live in cannot be adequately captured in language. We can think of language as a system for expressing relationships between objects, but the objects and relationships we carve out in language don't do justice to what actually exists in the world. I mean, I can say the phrase "John loves Amy", which is a relationship between two objects. But the words 'John' and 'Amy' aren't sufficient to specify two unique objects, and people write entire books on the word 'love' without quite grasping the full nature of that relation. To know what I mean by "John loves Amy" you need to be enmeshed in unspoken context — to have a sense of the world we live in beyond what I said — otherwise it's an empty phrase.

The dao is the way of the world, whether or not it can be expressed in language. We can't apply words to it — it isn't big or small, it isn't here or there, it isn't inside us or outside us — because words always miss its essence. If we say the dao is *this* then we also have to acknowledge that the dao is *not-this*. The dao is a whole, and our language only allows us to talk about parts and pieces.

The reason it seems like 'mysterious' language is that the text is trying to use language to talk about the idea that the world cannot properly be talked about in language. The proper approach to life — the 'de' part of daodejing, which translates as 'virtue' — is to know when one should stop trying to *know*, and know when one should stop trying to *do*. It's a way of listening to what the world is doing so that we know when to stop trying to impose our will, because the world - like water, which is the common analogy for the dao - is fundamentally unknowable, generously pliant, and ultimately unstoppable. It's a hard thing to talk about in the best case, and doubtless has gained confusions over a couple of millennia of recitation.

Comment: I can make some sense of that. What confuses me is what next? Is simply knowing that's the best approach to life is enough? Implausible. What should we do (or stop doing) in order to gain the necessary knowledge? Is the conclusion simply fatalism? Is the idea that once we've absorbed the knowledge, we'll just stop worrying about the issue?

Comment: @LudwigV: Daoism isn't exactly telling us what to do. Daoism is telling us how to approach the things we decide to do. There's a metaphor that the dao a is like shooting an arrow. We pull the bowstring back; the bottom of the bow comes up; the top of the bow comes down; that tension gives directed force for the arrow to fly true. But the dao goes on to say that humans tend to muck things up. Humans only want the bottom to come up, and never want the top to come down. That doesn't work; they shoot themselves in the foot or send a wild arrow who knows where...

Comment: @LudwigV: when you understand how a bow works and stop fighting against its nature, you can shoot an arrow. When you understand how the dao works and stop fighting against *its* nature, you can accomplish what you aim for. You just need to understand what to do, and when to let go.

Comment: A nice metaphor - and quite clear, in its way. I know enough to know that it isn't appropriate to go down the paths of Western philosophy. Indeed Daoism doesn't seem to be distinguishing itself from any philosophy, Western or Eastern. I mean, it seems to be distinguishing itself from common sense. But perhaps even that remark is a mistake.

Comment: But let me ask, whether reading the book is sufficient for understanding? (In the case of the bow and arrow, reading a book would never be sufficient). How do I know when I have understood?  Zen will tell me many things, but always return to inviting me to  sit down and shut up. In a way, that's not terribly helpful, but it is less unhelpful than nothing.

Comment: @LudwigV: Reading a book can help, but understanding is always a *going-beyond*. In this way a book is a bit like the bow cited above: it's not going to fire an arrow on its own, but it sure makes firing one easier. As for how to know... <shrug> it's the fisherman's paradox. Fisherman A grabs a fish and immediately drops it because it's so wiggly and slimy. Fisherman B grabs a fish and gets so invested in holding it that he tips himself over into the water. Fisherman C has the feel for when to hold on and when you let go. De is 'getting a feel' for the world.

Comment: I understand about the bow. I think I said already that reading a book would never be enough to shoot properly; you have to pick the actual bow up and actually shoot arrows; in doing that, you "get a feel". But this is different, because it is not like shooting a bow (or catching a fish). In those cases, it is clear what is success and what is failure. Since this book is about everything, there's no clear criterion. Or is that just a misunderstanding?

Comment: @LudwigV: Well, I suppose a daoist master would say that success is defined by failure, and failure by success. Neither is meaningful without the other, so neither is exactly 'real'. Catching a fish isn't a success, it's a meal, and if one makes it about success or failure one misses the entire point of fishing, and ends up hungry or wet.. It's not fatalism and it's not nihilism, it's a kind of metaphysical pragmatism.

Comment: @LudwigV: I mean, it's something like the Ancient Greek theater idea of hubris. Both tragic and comic figures defy the gods — indulge in hubris — and are destroyed for it (the main difference being that we sympathize with the tragic figure but not with the comic figure). But a heroic figure works with the gods and achieves his ends. *De* isn't heroism, but it is working with the natural flow of dao. It's not limiting; if you want to be a king, go try to be a king. But your ultimate success as a king will fall back on your conformance to dao.

Comment: We're about to be moved to chat. I'll draft something off line and bring it back later. I haven't much time just now.

Comment: a) I get the point about success or failure. Even Kipling managed to see through those. b) Don't you mean "But a heroic figure works with the gods and achieves his ends - or doesn't"? c) Is it like a sailing boat that has to work with the wind and the tide? But then, what do we say about super-tankers? Are they working with the dao? d) I guess the harder you try to work with the dao, the less you'll succeed. That's worth saying, I guess. e) I guess the point is a change in attitude that undermines the common sense approach to life as struggle and competition? Do you want to move to chat?